# g++ internal compiling error with chrono and thread headers

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to compile a multithreading program written in C++ running on WSL.

Here's what it looks like:

```
#include <thread>

void f() {}

int main()
{
std::thread t(f);
t.join();
return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile this I receive this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/chrono:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/thread:38,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/limits:1665:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 1665 |       min() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MIN__; }
      |       ^~~
0x7f7d7a46b08f ???
        /build/glibc-SzIz7B/glibc-2.31/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c:0
0x7f7d7a44c082 __libc_start_main
        ../csu/libc-start.c:308
```

I discovered the issue in the <chrono> header as this receives the same error:

```
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried compiling with `-pthread -std=c++17`. Additionally, I have tried updating g++ along with uninstalling it and reinstalling. None of this had any effect and the same error persisted.

Comment: I'd try a fresh WSL instance.

Comment: Good idea @HolyBlackCat, unfortunately it didn't do anything. I restarted WSL and also tried restarting the computer. Nothing different.

Comment: How did you "restart" WSL? My point was to clean the ubuntu installation, and reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu and the error is gone. Thanks @HolyBlackCat